# Secure cookie not being set on AWS ASP.NET MVC website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, iis-8, amazon-elb

We had a security review that revealed that the cookies in our ASP.NET MVC application were not being set as secure, despite having the following setting in web.config:

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true" />
```

The website is not using forms authentication so no need for `<forms requireSSL="true">` setting.

The website is hosted on an AWS app server and is accessed via an ELB. Internally on the app server the website is HTTP but externally it is HTTPS.

I've tried to implement a solution found here:

http://www.jamescrowley.co.uk/2014/03/07/ssl-termination-and-secure-cookiesrequiressl-with-asp-net-forms-authentication/

Added the following rewrite rules to this to web.config:

```
<rewrite>
   <rules>
        <rule name="HTTPS_AlwaysOn" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
            <serverVariables>
                <set name="HTTPS" value="on" />
            </serverVariables>
            <action type="None" />
            <conditions>
                <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" />
            </conditions>
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

And added HTTPS variable to the applicationHost.config to contain:

```
<rewrite>
    <allowedServerVariables>
        <add name="HTTPS" />
    </allowedServerVariables>
</rewrite>
```

Unfortunately this causes the ELB to fail. When speaking to our internal AWS support team they say this is because the ELB health check is failing. There is a health.html page in the root of the website. Is there a way of applying a condition to the above so that it ignores this for the health.html page which the ELB uses? I'm new to rewrite rules so not fully versed in the syntax and the way they work.

Comment: If you ever fixed this please let me know, I am having the exact same issue and tried and failed with the exact same fix you are using. In my case the "http" is coming from a load balancer.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this yet, but in theory I think you would just need to change your conditions:

```
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" >
            <add input="{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO}" pattern="https" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" negate="true" pattern="^/health.html$" ignoreCase="true" />
        </conditions>
```